# Multer diskStorage destination errors on production environment (vercel)

Tags: node.js, express, axios, multer, vercel

i am using react at front end and node js express js multer and mongodb at back end, **in development server(local host) its absolutely fine**, no error even testing with postman, but while i am using production server(deploying in vercel) its giving this error **"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/startupIcons/startupIcon-1673682105301-871934982.jpg'"** in axios put method response.

i tried change in directory, checked vercel production source directory(the folder is available there,) but nothing is working. **its multer specific error**

[image: 1]

multer configs

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.fieldname === 'startupIcon') {
            cb(null, '/public/images');
        } else if (file.fieldname === 'companyId') {
            cb(null, '/uploads/companyIds');
        } else if (file.fieldname === 'documents') {
            cb(null, '/uploads/companyIds');
        }
    },

    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      

        cb(null, `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')}-${file.originalname}`);
    },
   
});
const filter = (req, file, cb) => {
    const type = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
    if (file.fieldname === 'startupIcon') {
        if (type === 'jpg' || type === 'jpeg' || type === 'png') {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(new Error('Not a jpg/jpeg File!!'), false);
        }
    }
    if (file.fieldname === 'companyId' || file.fieldname === 'documents') {
        if (type === 'pdf' || type === 'jpg' || type === 'jpeg' || type === 'png') {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(new Error('file should be in .pdf|.jpg|.jpeg|.png format!!'), false);
        }
    }
};
const upload = multer({
    storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000,
        // fieldSize:  1016 * 1016,
    },
    fileFilter: filter,
});

module.exports = upload;
```

Comment: Please show the multer configuration and replace a link with the screenshot with formatted text block.

Comment: @Anatoly multer configs added

Comment: I suspect you need to use an absolute path in `destination`'s `cb` calls using `__dirname`

Comment: i found that the issue is with vercel. it may not allow file uploading file in a free slot. rectify me, if I am wrong. as I had to use file storage provider according to vercel website. https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-upload-and-store-files-with-vercel

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really simple. Nextjs does not want you to change or add files to your public folder after deploy. Its also no vercel issue. You can try it local if you make an build and use next start. It will also not work. Its an security thing that next only allowes to access files in public that are existing on build time. Nextjs wants you to use cdn's for dynamic files instead. What we do is using an other folder called files/assets or uploads. And change our nginx or apache proxy config so nginx or apache delivers the files in that folder. If we dont have the possibility we create an asset api endpoint which delivers files from said folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "/tmp" folder to temporarily save files in serverless functions before uploading them to a more permanent storage solution. Files cannot be written to other locations after deployment.

for more info you can see [vercel files in serverless functions](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions) and [temporary storage](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions#using-temporary-storage) doc.